# Schedule some task at reboot of the server

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

In my server, I have some tasks scheduled which are running in the background threads and if I restart my server all those scheduled tasks will be gone.

So I have added all the scheduled tasks in the database and now whenever the server is restarted I want to again schedule all the tasks which were present in the database.

So is there any way to execute a set of functions whenever the server is rebooted?

Comment: Use something like quartz, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @M.Deinum can I use it to schedule tasks dynamically during runtime ?

Comment: Yes... It is a very complete and persistent scheduler.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok thanks I will check it out.